# Can I run function of multiple Google sheets from Master Google Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created 10 Google sheets ( copies of parent sheet) which has the same code seperately.
I want to run some function in all 10 Google sheets from the Parent Google sheet.
For Example I want to run the following function in all 10 sheets without opening  them from the parent Google sheet.
Ex to delete all Entries in 10 sheets

function deleteentries ()

Is it possible by using Google sheet url?
Or provide me any other solution.

I am new to appScript so explain your answer  step by step.

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED:

1. Collect all sheet IDs:
   Sheet Id can be taken from link:
   'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
2. Put them into array:
   `var sheets = ['xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'];`
3. Build loop function (just copy and paste it into your project, with valid sheet Ids of course):

   ```
   var sheets = ['xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'];
   function loopAndDoSomething(){
      for (var d=0; sheets.length; d++){
         deleteentries(sheets[d]);
      }
    }
   ```

4.Define `deleteentries()` and make sure it knows what to do with parameter you send from the loop:

```
   function deleteentries(sheetId){
      SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId)
      .getSheetByName('sheet name must be the same in all spreadsheets')
      .getRange(1,1).clear();
    }
```

This example will delete values in cell "A1" in all sheet, that you put into array.

Comment: Sir , I am started to learn this kind of stuff since january.....if you explain your your idea step by step with example,i can understand easily...sorry for asking again ? @Ricardas